# Export all Delicious bookmarks

Tags: export, backup, delicious

The canonical backup link of Delicious, https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/all, only returns 1000 bookmarks now! Any ideas how to get all my bookmarks? This is for my [export script](https://github.com/l0b0/export/blob/master/Delicious.sh), which worked until the new owners took over.

[The old api.del.icio.us](http://leo.gaggl.com/2011/10/export-delicious-bookmarks-in-xml/) (98.139.50.166) seems to be down, so that's not an option (besides, I want to download *everything*, not all my old plus 1000 of my new bookmarks).

Comment: I changed your answer to an edit. If you actually have the script available for public release you can use that as your answer. For example, the latest working version of the script.

Comment: That wouldn't be versioned, so I prefer not to create a copy here.

Comment: Some of the links in this question seem to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like nobody else had got this going yet, so I spent an evening getting the [export script](https://raw.github.com/l0b0/export/master/Delicious.sh) working again, fetching chunks of 1000 bookmarks at a time:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# NAME
#        Delicious.sh - Download your bookmarks
#
# SYNOPSIS
#        Delicious.sh <username> <password> <save path>
#
# DESCRIPTION
#        Downloads the bookmarks at Delicious as an XML file.
#
#        How to export at midnight every day:
#
#        First, make sure nobody else can read your crontab. If not, they can
#        get access to your password, and I'm not good at sympathy.
#
#        $ git clone git://github.com/l0b0/export.git
#
#        $ crontab -e
#
#        Insert a new line with the following contents (replacing the example
#        paths and login with your own):
#
#        @midnight /.../export/Delicious.sh user password /.../bookmarks.xml
#
# BUGS
#        https://github.com/l0b0/export/issues
#
# COPYRIGHT AND LICENSE
#        Copyright (C) 2010, 2011 Victor Engmark
#
#        This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#        it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#        the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#        (at your option) any later version.
#
#        This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#        but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#        MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#        GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#        You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#        along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
################################################################################
set -o errexit -o nounset

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    echo 'Wrong parameters - See the documentation on top of the script'
    exit 1
fi

USERNAME="$1"
PASSWORD="$2"
EXPORT_PATH="$3"

# Export
EXPORT_URL=https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/all
EXPORT_DATE="$(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)"
chunk_size=1000 # Delicious now only supports exporting 1000 bookmarks at a time
header_lines=3
chunk_lines=$(($chunk_size + $header_lines))
EXPORT_COMPATIBILITY='
s#^<posts \(tag="[^"]*"\) \(total="[^"]*"\) \(user="[^"]*"\)>#<posts \3 update="'$EXPORT_DATE'" \1 \2>#;
s#^<post \(description="[^"]*"\) \(extended="[^"]*"\) \(hash="[^"]*"\) \(href="[^"]*"\) private="[^"]*" shared="[^"]*" \(tag="[^"]*"\) \(time="[^"]*"\)/>#  <post \4 \3 \1 \5 \6 \2 meta="" />#'
EXPORT_REMOVE_LINES='3,${/^</d}'
bookmark_prefix='<post '

> "$EXPORT_PATH" # Empty bookmarks file

bookmarks_count() {
    # How many bookmarks have we fetched?
    grep -o "${bookmark_prefix}" "$EXPORT_PATH" | wc -l || true
}

while [ $(($(bookmarks_count) % $chunk_size)) -eq 0 ]
do
    wget \
        --user="$USERNAME" --password="$PASSWORD" \
        -O- \
        --no-check-certificate \
        "$EXPORT_URL?start=$(bookmarks_count)" >> "$EXPORT_PATH"
done
sed -i -e 's#><#>\n<#g' "$EXPORT_PATH" # Introduce newlines
sed -i -e "$EXPORT_COMPATIBILITY" "$EXPORT_PATH"
sed -i -e "$EXPORT_REMOVE_LINES" "$EXPORT_PATH"
echo '</posts>' >> "$EXPORT_PATH"
```

This script is **no longer maintained** by me, since I've moved to the non-free [Pinboard](https://pinboard.in), an extremely fast (little JavaScript), feature-complete (e.g., being able to modify large amounts of bookmarks) and reliable (no downtime since I migrated seven months ago) alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following tags:

`&start={xx}` (optional) → Start returning posts this many results into the set.

`&results={xx}` (optional) → Return this many results.

`&fromdt={CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ}` (optional) → Filter for posts on this date or later

`&todt={CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ}` (optional) → Filter for posts on this date or earlier

Info about the API can be found here: http://www.delicious.com/developers